# Suitable amplifier for solid Tenor Ukulele

Tags: amplifiers, ukulele

I am looking for the right type of amplifier for my new solid KOA koaloha tenor uke.   I tried a small guitar amp (a Roland Cube) but it doesn't seem to do anything special for it and in a large room the sound is lost.   I have an active pick up and wondered what type and size of amplifier would bring out the charm of my new uke.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that the pickup have is designed for acoustic instruments, in which case you will need a suitable acoustic amplifier, such as an acoustic guitar amp, or a PA system.  I believe the Roland Cube amps are electric guitar amplifiers, which will not work so well.